# converting a list of string with the format 68.830320 in 'time' format without date information. The time format is second.millisecond

Tags: python, date, datetime, converters

I have a string in the form of 68.830320 Format. this I need to convert to time Format in second.millisecond. it does not contain date or any other values. I cannot use strptime since the Format is not right. tstamp that I'm trying to parse is a list of calues containg values with decimal Point. I cannot round this value. it still gives error. I'm not sure how to proceeed. please help!

tried a lot of threads from here that always take the datetime object. But since my Format is not in the same way, I cannot use that info. I have tries .time dateutil, and everything else available. I still cannot solve this problem

```
 tstamp = child2.get('timestamp').replace(" ", "").replace("\n", "")
                        print(tstamp)
                        parser.parser(tstamp)
                        format_time = datetime.date(tstamp)
                        print(format_time)
```

Answer (score 1):

A number of seconds isn't a `datetime`, it's a `timedelta`. It isn't a `datetime` because you can't take the string `"68.830320"` and set the hands on a wall clock to represent that time.

Convert your string to a `timedelta` like this:

```
>>> from datetime import timedelta
>>> mytime = timedelta(seconds=float("68.830320"))
>>> mytime
datetime.timedelta(0, 68, 830320)
```

You can then add the `timedelta` to a `datetime` to get a wall clock time.

Comment: @user11236564 If the answer worked for you, please accept it.